# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am not quite understanding this compile error because I don't get this error and can compile and run on a real device, but if I try to build and run on a simulator I get this error.

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat)'

Here is the line of code that causes the error:

```
loadingNotification.yOffset = CGFloat(CGRectGetMinY(self.tableView.bounds))
```

Furthermore if I change it to

```
loadingNotification.yOffset = Float(CGRectGetMinY(self.tableView.bounds))
```

It works on the simulators but not on the real device I get

> 'Cannot assign value of type 'Float' to type 'CGFloat'

Any ideas to as why this is behaving like this?

Comment: `CGRectGetMinY()` returns already a CGFloat. Are you using Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick; what's the type of `loadingNotification`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write just this:

```
#if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
    loadingNotification.yOffset = Float(CGRectGetMinY(self.tableView.bounds))
#else
    loadingNotification.yOffset = CGRectGetMinY(self.tableView.bounds)
#endif
```

Anyway try to understand why you have `CGFloat` in device and `Float` in sim

Comment: This works for a real device but produces this error when trying to run on a simulator: `Cannot assign value of type 'CGFloat' to type 'Float'`

Comment: This means that in the sim your yOffset is a Float..did you manage something different for sim?

Comment: Not intentionally but its possible, I just have no clue where to look.

Comment: I found the issue, your answer also helped correct my code so I will accept it. This is what fixed the sim: Xcode -> window-> organizer->Projects then select and delete your project derived data.